# React app : old version kept in cache until I inspect it

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, create-react-app

I used `create-react-app` to start working on a React app. By default, it uses service workers. I also happen to serve my production app with https.

It turns out that with this config, my browser just doesn't get new versions I deploy. It keeps on reloading old versions, even if I force a refresh. The only way I can get it to load the latest build is by inspecting the page (with Chrome). Then, when I force-refresh, the latest build is loaded.

I have disabled the service worker as it seemed to be the culprit, but I keep on bumping into this problem. I can't ask my users to each open the inspector in their browsers in order to get the latest build.

How can I find out how to fix this problem? Is there a `create-react-app` config I could change in order to make sure this does not happen anymore?

Comment: What caching headers does your hosting platform set to your service-worker.js file?

Comment: `cache-control:public, max-age=86400`. From what I understand, this is why the service worker is so sticky.

I'd also like to know what the service worker is supposed to do. I thought it was supposed to help update the app to the latest version more smoothly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've actually found what the problem was: the `index.html` was cached, and so it was pointing to old js files which were also cached.

The way I solved it was to add this config to an `.htaccess` file at the root of the app (although configuring apache through other means might also work):

```
<FilesMatch "\.(html)$">
  FileETag None
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
     Header unset ETag
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
     Header set Pragma "no-cache"
     Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

In the end, it was unrelated to the service worker. It only had to do with the way `index.html` was cached.

Comment: Did you try updating the version in package.json file? Doesn't it work?

Answer (score 2):

For someone who is using nginx to serve their react app:

```
location / {
    add_header Cache-Control "private, no-store, no-cache";
}
```

(see syntax in http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header).

JS and CSS are usually versioned, but html should be served with `no-store, no-cache` to load latest.
Make sure that later rules in the config that match html don't override the `Cache-Control`.

Also make sure that you do cache your static elements like .js, .css, .svg, but there should be a separate location rule serving those anyways.

Comment: Nothing is cached if you go with this option.

Comment: If this is all you put in your nginx config then no, nothing will be cached. But if you only apply this rule to the core html file and add a `/static` rule for js/css/images then those files, which will be the bulk of the content for a CRA app will be cached, but the correct version will always be served as the html file is mostly just a version list for which js and css files to load.

Comment: Thanks akaltar - i'll give that a try. I'm quite new to nginx.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the server sets caching headers in a way that tells the browser *not to update* the service-worker.js file as quickly as you would have hoped. The SW.js file should have Expires: 0, Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache headers. Note that the headers are set by the server serving the website, not the CRA or any other build tool used to create the app.

For an introduction to Service Workers themselves, check out Google's post over here https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I am not sure about this, but I knew that updating the version in package.json file was supposed to do this work. Otherwise what's the use of this version property?

From:

```
  "version": "1.0.0",
```

To:

```
  "version": "2.0.0",
```

It worked for me though.